# Can reactjs code added to html file throgh link tag read data from server side

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I have a html file which has a link to reactjs file. can it read data from node server ??

Comment: Why do you even need that, I mean that's not the way you use these front-end libraries. If you are facing problems in SEO then you can implement the server side rendering in React.js

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can [`renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) to render your jsx file to string and return that string to your client so that it injects it into DOM.

```
const response = await fetch('/render-endpoint?file=some-file.jsx');
const rendered = await response.text();
document.getElementById('some-element').innerHTML = rendered;
```